# prevent update from kernel driver

Tags: drivers, kernel

I had to install the driver for rtl8723de wifi network controller because ubuntu doesn't include this driver. Last time I updated ubuntu, I lost this configuration and had to install the driver again.
Now I want to update ubuntu, and don't want to lose the driver.

How can I "mark" it to not be updated?

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8319
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
Kernel modules: rtl8723de
```

Comment: Install the driver using dkms.

Comment: that's how I installed it both times. And with last update I did, I lost the driver

Comment: It means that you did something wrong. Which Ubuntu release you are using? What is the output of `dkms status`?

Comment: rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.0.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed     Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: So what is the Ubuntu release?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: And what is the current kernel? `uname -a`.

Comment: Linux david-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You need to update the system and install a proper driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 using dkms. The 5.0.0-32 is obsolete.

Comment: ok I'll try. Thanks for the help